# Where should I place the ammeter to measure current flow between A0 and GND of the Arduino here

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, breadboard

I was trying to build a circuit in [tinkercad](https://www.tinkercad.com) that plots the voltage/current across A0 and GND pins of Ardunio. To confirm that the plots displayed on the screen are correct, I decided to also add voltmeter/ammeter to the circuit.

The circuit that came into my mind for it is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSp0ck.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My tinkercad implementation of it is shown below (I used a 3V battery and a potentiometer together, for obtaining variable voltage):
[image]
<sup>Double click on the image to zoom, if it's not clear</sup>

It seems to be working well while plotting the voltmeter readings, but **I am not able to make the ammeter measure currents at all. Its readings are always coming out zero, for all voltage values.** As far as I can see, it is connected in series like it should be. **What is the problem here?**

The schematic diagram generated for the above circuit is:
[image]

<sup>**Edit:** made modifications as suggested by @Javier Gonzalez Cuervos</sup>

Comment: Can TinkerCAD produce schematic diagrams?

Comment: Yes, it can. But it's not showing any ammeter/voltmeter in them.

Comment: I asked for a schematic because it isn't clear from the wiring diagram just what you are trying to do.  Schematics are usually clearer as to intent than wiring diagram.

Comment: I've added the schematics to make the question more detailed.

Comment: The ammeter is measuring the current going to the analog read input, showing zero as it should. Do you want, instead to measure the current through the load?

Comment: There’s no 0V/gnd connection in your schematic. Current must flow in a loop.

Comment: @devnull I'm trying to measure current flow between the A0 and GND terminals, which I guess is same as the current through the load.

Comment: In the "circuit that came into my mind", there is no current flowing anywhere. The generated schematic does not match the wiring diagram. Maybe we should take a step back: forget about the connection with the arduino for a moment and try do describe what you are trying to experiment and measure. **Edit:** now the schematic has the proper connection and A0 will measure the voltage divider output.

Comment: I am myself not clear about the direction of current in the circuit, because I don't know if Arduino generates current there, & if it does then how much. And the schematic was generated by tinkercad for the shown connection, and there is nothing I can do to change it.

Comment: How are you measuring current?  Picture of meter showing connections.

Comment: Current into an Arduino input will be under a milliamp. Current in/out of an output will be in the mA range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where should I place the ammeter to measure current flow between A0 and GND of the Arduino here

You placed it correctly, and this current is zero. If, instead you and to measure the current flowing in the circuit, see below:

[image]

The wires with blue Xs have practically zero current.

The current circulating is fixed:

\$\frac{3}{50+501} = 5.4 mA\$

The voltage you measure at A0 varies from 0V to:

\$ \frac{3\times500}{500+51} = 2.72 V\$

which is the output of the voltage divider.

Note that if you measure the current where there is one, tinkercad shows this (two potentiometer settings):

[image]

[image]

But no current in this wire:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the extra clarification. Although I can't really find a place for putting these flows in the question. The first circuit diagram does not have any potentiometer, the rest are just screenshots. I guess keeping it here for now should be fine.

Comment: Ok. No problem. You are trying to measure current where there is none, so, it seems I can't contribute any further.

Comment: Can you suggest a postition/resistance value for an extra resistor to increase the current in the circuit. I tried different combinations but the ammeter is just always stuck at 0.

Comment: Regardless of the resistance values you use, you will keep reading zero current if you put the ammeter in a place where there is no current. If you, instead, interrupt one of the wires which do have current (shown above) and tinkercad works properly, it you show you the current. To be clear, I'm referring to the wiring diagram or the circuit above. The circuit you put in circuitlab is different and has no current flowing, anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Check your tinkercad schematic and compare it to your circuit design. You will notice that in the schematic you have the voltage supply in parallel with your Ammeter and thus there is no current passing through it. Hence the reading.

Simply take the ground wire of your voltage supply and connect it to the ground pin on the Arduino board.

Comment: I made the change, but the reading is still zero. Should the ammeter be placed in a different spot to measure the current between A0 and GND?

Comment: If my colourblindness is not betraying me, you are using a 510 or 520 (can't tell if that's red or brown) resistor. At 1.34V, this circuit is drawing 2.62 mA which is really near the minimum resolution of your Ammeter (1mA). Try using a smaller resistor?

Comment: Actually, now that I see it better, the resistor is in series with a potentiometer so you are using it as a voltage divider to lower the voltage of the supply. I see what the problem is now: You have no load on your circuit, ergo, no current.

Comment: I tried connecting resistor both in parallel and series, still no any change. Tried altering the values of the resistances too.